# How to merge "several function templates" with parameters of "different std::class types" into one - but still keep connection inside with parameters

Tags: c++

How can I merge "the 2 following function templates" into a single one, but can still keep the connection of the function parameter with any relevant type inside the function.

Any solution, please? thank everyone in advance

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <forward_list>
#include <vector>

template <class T> void prinList(std::list<T> list){
    for (auto var : list){ std::cout << var << " "; }
    std::cout << '\n';

    //the following block has no practical use, just for the sake of questioning
    std::vector<T> vec; //this line has connection with parameter
    auto it1= list.begin();
    auto it2= list.end();
    vec.assign(it1,it2);
}
template <class T> void prinList(std::forward_list<T> list){
    for (auto var : list){ std::cout << var << " "; }
    std::cout << '\n';

    //the following block has no practical use, just for the sake of questioning
    std::vector<T> vec; //this line has connection with parameter
    auto it1= list.begin();
    auto it2= list.end();
    vec.assign(it1,it2);
}
int main(){
    std::forward_list<int> F_list1={1,2,3,4,5};
    prinList(F_list1);

    std::list<int> list1={10,11,12,13};
    prinList(list1);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't spam tags!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two options come to mind. The first one is to use iterators instead of containers:

```
template <typename It> void prinList(It first, It last){
    for (auto it = first; it != last; ++it){ std::cout << *it << " "; }
    std::cout << '\n';
    
    std::vector<typename std::iterator_traits<It>::value_type> vec;
    vec.assign(first,last);
}
```

This is what the standard library typically does when working with collections of elements: take in a range (pair of iterators) instead of a container.

The second is to make the containers themselves be the template parameter, and use their `value_type` member:

```
template <class T> void prinList(T const & list){
    for (auto var : list){ std::cout << var << " "; }
    std::cout << '\n';
    
    std::vector<typename T::value_type> vec;
    auto it1= list.begin();
    auto it2= list.end();
    vec.assign(it1,it2);
}
```

If you want to restrict `T` to `std::list` and `std::forward_list` only, you can make a type trait:

```
template<typename T>
struct IsListOrForwardList : std::false_type {};

template<typename T>
struct IsListOrForwardList<std::list<T>> : std::true_type {};

template<typename T>
struct IsListOrForwardList<std::forward_list<T>> : std::true_type {};
```

and then use `static_assert` or SFINAE or concepts (in C++20):

```
template<typename T>
concept ListOrForwardList = IsListOrForwardList<T>::value;

template <ListOrForwardList T> void prinList(T const & list) { ... }
```

As Jarod42 points out in a comment, instead of using a simple template parameter, you can use a template template parameter:

```
template <template <typename, typename...> class C, typename T, typename... Ts>
void prinList(C<T, Ts...> const & list) requires ListOrForwardList<C<T, Ts...>> {
    for (auto var : list){ std::cout << var << " "; }
    std::cout << '\n';
    
    std::vector<T> vec;
    auto it1= list.begin();
    auto it2= list.end();
    vec.assign(it1,it2);
}
```

This allows you to use `T` directly in place of `typename T::value_type`. The `requires` clause is optional of course, just here to demonstrate how to combine this with a constraint.

Comment: 3rd option with template template parameter: `template <template <typename, typename...> class C, typename T, typename... Ts>void prinList(C<T, Ts...> const & list)`.

Comment: All solutions required only: `std::vector<...> vec{std::cbegin(list), std::cend(list)}`, or even  `std::vector<...> vec{list}`, even in OP as well.

Comment: thanks @Nelfeal , thank JeJo , didn't expect get more than what I could imagine, best wish! :)